# Using a javascript function to load a page in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to use a Javascript function to load a web page in an iframe named "cake". How can I do that?

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick=[function]>Load page in iframe</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `iframe` named "cake" in your HTML, but in general, `document.frames['cake'].location.href = what_ever;`. Or give an `id`for your `iframe` and say `document.getElementById('iframe_id').src ='what_ever';`. Also it's recommended to get familiar with [the elements you're working with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) ...

Comment: I know, making an iframe named "cake" is what I want (intend) to make.

Comment: You're asking how to access an iframe, not how to create a one ...

Answer (score 27):

```js
function changeUrl() {
    var site = "https://www.google.com/";
    document.getElementsByName('iFrameName')[0].src = site;
}
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
        <body>
          <button onclick="changeUrl()">Load page in iframe</button>
          <iframe name="iFrameName"></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: OP has a name, not id?

Comment: wc.. :).. can you please upvote it.. i m trying to earn some reputation.. so that i could contribute more..:)

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```html
<html>

<head>


<script type="text/javascript">

function changeUrl() {
    var site = "1.wav";
    document.getElementsByName('cake')[0].src = site;
}


</script>


</head>

<body>


<center>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" height=400 width=400 frameborder=0 name = "cake" style =""></></iframe>

<br>

<br>

<button onclick="changeUrl()">Load page in iframe</button>

</center>


</body>

</html>
```